# Empty set after collectAsList, even though it is not empty inside the transformation operator

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin

I am trying to figure out if I can work with Kotlin and Spark,
and use the former's data classes instead of Scala's case classes.

I have the following data class:

```
data class Transaction(var context: String = "", var epoch: Long = -1L, var items: HashSet<String> = HashSet()) :
    Serializable {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private val serialVersionUID = 1L
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of the main routine looks like this:

```
val transactionEncoder = Encoders.bean(Transaction::class.java)
val transactions = inputDataset
    .groupByKey(KeyExtractor(), KeyExtractor.getKeyEncoder())
    .mapGroups(TransactionCreator(), transactionEncoder)
    .collectAsList()

transactions.forEach { println("collected Transaction=$it") }
```

With `TransactionCreator` defined as:

```
class TransactionCreator : MapGroupsFunction<Tuple2<String, Timestamp>, Row, Transaction> {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private val serialVersionUID = 1L
    }

    override fun call(key: Tuple2<String, Timestamp>, values: MutableIterator<Row>): Transaction {
        val seq = generateSequence { if (values.hasNext()) values.next().getString(2) else null }
        val items = seq.toCollection(HashSet())
        return Transaction(key._1, key._2.time, items).also { println("inside call Transaction=$it") }
    }
}
```

However, I think I'm running into some sort of serialization problem,
because the set ends up empty after collection.
I see the following output:

```
inside call Transaction=Transaction(context=context1, epoch=1000, items=[c])
inside call Transaction=Transaction(context=context1, epoch=0, items=[a, b])
collected Transaction=Transaction(context=context1, epoch=0, items=[])
collected Transaction=Transaction(context=context1, epoch=1000, items=[])
```

I've tried a custom `KryoRegistrator` to see if it was a problem with Kotlin's `HashSet`:

```
class MyRegistrator : KryoRegistrator {
    override fun registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
        kryo.register(HashSet::class.java, JavaSerializer()) // kotlin's HashSet
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to help.
Any other ideas?

Full code [here](https://github.com/asardaes/hello-spark-kotlin/tree/31209a0dbd2cf1b3bfb46fdabb15f7a6a04e8847).

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a serialization issue.
The documentation of `Encoders.bean` states (Spark v2.4.0):

> collection types: only array and java.util.List currently, map support is in progress

Porting the `Transaction` data class to Java and changing `items` to a `java.util.List` seems to help.